# How can I solve this 'git pull' error due to new/changed tags?

Tags: git

I am trying to pull from a git repository, but it errors, not sure why. Seems it's something to do with changed or new tags:

> error: 'refs/tags/v3' exists; cannot create 'refs/tags/v3/0.1' From
>   https://bitbucket.org/*****/*******  ! [new tag]         v3/0.1
>   -> v3/0.1  (unable to update local ref) error: some local refs could not be updated; try running  'git remote prune origin' to remove any
>   old, conflicting branches

I have tried 'git remote prune origin', but it doesn't seem to fix anything.

I have no tag "v3/0.1" in my local repository. I have a tag for a commit which is "v3_2", and the remote repo has two tags on that commit "v3_2" and "v3/0.1". So I suspect that either my local git doesn't accept two tags, which would be strange, or the "/" is causing the problems.

Any ideas about how to solve this, or how to find out more about what's causing the error?

Comment: Do you have a tag `v3`, like the error message seems to indicate? If so, can you remove that, or do you still need it?

Comment: I didn't have a "v3" tag locally. I had "v3_1" and "v3_2" tags, but removing those didn't help. In the end I just cloned the whole remote repo back. But I wonder if there's any other way to fix it that doesn't require a full redo.

Answer (score 1):

you can have tags something/ABC, something/DEF

but you can't have tag by name something. Reason in this case "something" can't be file and folder at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

`git remote prune` removes branches but here you've got a conflicting `tag`.

Create a backup and remove your local tag that is conflicting.

```
git tag v3/0.1b v3/0.1
git tag -d v3/0.1
```

Then pull again. Check that it did want you wanted and remove your backup tag:

```
git -d v3/0.1b
```

Comment: I have no tag "v3/0.1" in my local repository. I have a tag for a commit which is "v3_2", and the remote repo has two tags on that commit "v3_2" and "v3/0.1". So I suspect that either my local git doesn't accept two tags, which would be strange, or the "/" is causing the problems.